# loop executes only last array element using php, ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Hi friends am trying to save the data from the loop here is my code.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body onload="searchVideo();">
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `playlists`";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $id=$row['id'];
          $playlists=$row['playlists'];
          $myArray = explode(',', $playlists);
              $length =  sizeof( $myArray);
              $myArray[0]=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-
              $myArray[1]=PLFgquLnL59ak1QNHmrUSjNM6WTegpgX__
              for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
               echo "
                  <script>
                    var pageToken = '';
                    var numOfResult = 0;
                    var maxResults = 200;
                    function searchVideo(){
                    var separator = ',';
                    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken=' + pageToken + '&playlistId=$myArray[$i]&key=APIKEY&callback=?',function(data){
                    var l = data.items.length;
                    pageToken = data.nextPageToken;
                    numOfResult += l;
                    var itemUrl = '';
                    var videoids = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    if( i == 0) {
                        separator = ',';
                       }
                   else {
                       separator = ',';
                   }
                   var videoid = data.items[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                   var title = data.items[i].snippet.title;

                   $.ajax({
                     method: 'POST',
                     url:    'add.php',
                    data: { title: title, videoid: videoid }
                   })
                  .done(function(data) {

                 });
              }

            if( numOfResult <= maxResults) {
               searchVideo();

            }
    });

}

    </script>
    ";
              }

    }



?>
```

add.php

```
<?php
 $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['title']);
 $videoid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['videoid']);
 $thumbnail_url = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$videoid.'/hqdefault.jpg';

  $sql = "INSERT INTO ytfb(name,video_name,thumbnail_url)     VALUES('$title','$videoid','$thumbnail_url')";
    $create_post_query=mysqli_query($mysql,$sql);
        if(!$create_post_query)
      {
        die("Connection failed".mysqli_error($mysql));
       }
 ?>
```

When am trying to save the data using ajax in add.php the elements from the last array element are only saved the elements from the first array element is not saved how can I be able to save the data from all the array elements. Can anyone please help me out with this

Comment: These rows looks strange strange. `$myArray[0]=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-`. Is that suppose to be a string? In it's current format, that should throw errors.

Comment: You're adding `n * m` times the same script element, where `n` is the number of rows in the `playlists` table and `m` the number of playlists in the column `playlists` of each row O.o

Comment: @Andreas I didnot understand clearly can you please tell me what is the error in there

Comment: @Andreas I need to change only the playlist for each loop so I have given $myArray[$i] which loops through array

Comment: You are redefining the same function with different body in every pass. I don't think this will work properly.

Comment: You're also redefining the same global JS variables on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function searchVideo outside the cycle and organize to call it with different parameters. In cycle change global vars or input parameters of searchVideo.
Now you get this result because finaly executes the last istance of this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    if( i == 0) {
                        separator = ',';
                       }
                   else {
                       separator = ',';
                   }
                   var videoid = data.items[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                   var title = data.items[i].snippet.title;
```

Here i will be the index of last element so only last item is getting stored.
You have to loop the ajax call through the loop to get all elements to be saved.

Comment: how can i make ajax call through the loop as ajax call is in the loop